# Book Identification with Q

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, borg, star-trek-q

I'm interested in the title of the book where the Borg Queen attempts to assimilate Q, but the nanoprobes have zero effect. I think I want to purchase this book online, so please don't include any spoilers (no Q-uotes, etc.). Thanks.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/217901.Q_A ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the [*Strange New Worlds IV*](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Strange_New_Worlds_IV) anthology story [*Iridium-7-Tetrahydroxate Crystals Are a Girl's Best Friend*](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Iridium-7-Tetrahydroxate_Crystals_Are_a_Girl%27s_Best_Friend) in which Q tries to woo the Borg Queen. She's surprisingly chilled out about it.

> *“Is this going to take much longer?” said the man* [Q] *as the Borg
>   repeatedly injected nanoprobes into his upper arm. He was lying on the
>   assimilation gurney as Borg bioengineering drones looked him over.
>   There were no oddities in his DNA, no antibodies that would halt
>   nanoprobe activities, nothing out of the ordinary.*
>
> *The door to the assimilation chamber irised open and the Borg queen
>   entered. She was medium height, about five and a half feet. Before
>   assimilation she must have been quite striking. Now she was a hideous
>   monstrosity. Her remaining eye was a sparkling brown color. The other
>   eye socket had an optical reader jutting out of it.*
>
> *“Resistance is futile,” she said.
>
>   “I’m not resisting!”*